# Ideal space for partition to install Ubuntu

Tags: installation, partitioning, live-cd, gparted

I have a 60GB Toshiba satellite Laptop with XP Pro with one partition (27 GB are used by xp and 28GB are free). I am going to create a partition (with GParted from Ubuntu 12.04 boot CD) and after that I'll install 12.04 from the same CD.

How much space is ideal for this partition?

Comment: Spellcheck!  I, too, have a laptot (small human), as well as a lapcat.

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to give Ubuntu about 20 to 25GB max if you only have 28GB free.

Make sure you defragment the hard drive using Windows first.

There is no need to manually partition the drive, from the Ubuntu installer select 'install alongside windows' and you will then be able to change the recommended partition size using a slider.

Answer (score 1):

The system itself uses 5-10 GB with plenty of software installed. A 10-15GB /root partition should be sufficient for the system and software. How much you need above that is up to you and depends on what do you want to use Ubuntu for.

Nowadays, you can resize and move partitions with relative ease, so that partitioning need not to be final.

If I can give a one piece of advise, however, then consider creating separate partitions for /root (system and software) and /home. Although that may lead to wasting space (for example because there is space on the /root partition that you don't use), it saves a lot of hustle in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Answers for this will be very subjective.  Generally, I just split the available space, leaving at least 25G.  If you've got around 30G, just use that.